# RouteLocatorBuilder' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am pretty new with angular apps and i received this error trying to build my application:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-06-18 16:04:48.462[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10351[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method routes in io.github.cursodesouza.mscloudgateway.MscloudgatewayApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder' in your configuration.

Can anyone help me please?

Tks.

Below ins my Main and .yml and .pom files.

Main

```
package io.github.cursodesouza.mscloudgateway;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MscloudgatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MscloudgatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes (RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder
                .routes()
                    .route(r -> r.path("/clientes/**").uri("lb://msclientes"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

.pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.github.cursodesouza</groupId>
    <artifactId>mscloudgateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mscloudgateway</name>
    <description>Cloud Gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: mscloudgateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enable: true
          lower-case-service-id: true

server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've been dealing with the same issue and haven't found a solution, yet. Just finding a minimalistic and working spring gateway rate limiting sample project seems impossible.

Diving into the rabbit hole by declaring the bean myself didn't help either as it continues asking for more and more beans which I feel is not the way to implement this.

Let me know if you find a solution, I'll do the same... good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that worked for me. It's not your exact case as it uses redis and doesn't implement Eureka, but it could help either you or someone else who might encounter this issue.

Credit goes to Baeldung and his spring-cloud-gateway-2 which I used as a base and I just fixed/modified whatever wasn't working for me.

In my case the issue with RouteLocatorBuilder showed up when I was missing the spring-cloud-dependencies in dependency management. Which you seem to have, but maybe there's a version mismatch? Can you try the versions I'm using?

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: RateLimitingSample
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enable: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
  data:
    redis:
      database: 0
      host: localhost
      port: 6379
      password:
      connect-timeout: 60000
```

application runnable

```
package org.example.springcloudgateway.ipaddress;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ratelimit.RedisRateLimiter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication()
public class IpAddressApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(IpAddressApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("requestratelimiter_route", p -> p
                        .path("/example")
                        .filters(f -> f.requestRateLimiter(r -> r.setRateLimiter(redisRateLimiter())))
                        .uri("http://example.org"))
                .route("ipaddress_route", p -> p
                        .path("/example2")
                        .filters(f -> f.requestRateLimiter(r -> r.setRateLimiter(redisRateLimiter())
                                .setDenyEmptyKey(false)
                                .setKeyResolver(new SimpleClientAddressResolver())))
                        .uri("http://example.org"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisRateLimiter redisRateLimiter()
    {
        return new RedisRateLimiter(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RateLimitingTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Embedded Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- exclude logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is ussualy caused by non-compatible version of `spring-cloud` and `spring-boot` dependencies.
You can check compatibility matrix here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Also you can look for `GatewayAutoConfiguration` where this bean should be created and check all the conditions (annotations).